# Elegant way to combineLatest without dropping values and imbalanced publishers in Swift Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have two Publishers A and B. They are imbalanced as in A will emit 3 values, then complete, B will only emit 1 value, then complete (A actually can emit a variable number, B will remain 1 if that helps):

```
A => 1,   2,   3
B =>         X
```

B also runs asynchronously and will likely only emit a value after A already emitted its second value (see diagram above). (B might also only emit any time, including after A already completed.)

I'd like to publish tuples of A's values combined with B's values:

```
(1, X) (2, X) (3, X)
```

`combineLatest` is not up for the job as it will skip the first value of A and only emit `(2, X)` and `(3, X)`. `zip` on the other hand will not work for me, because B only emits a single value.

I am looking for an *elegant*  way to accomplish this. Thanks!

---

*Edit and approach to a solution*

A bit philosophical, but I think there is fundamental question if you want to go the `zip` or `combineLatest` route. You definitely need some kind of storage for the faster publisher to buffer events while you wait for the slower to start emitting values.

One solution might be to create a publisher that collects events from A until B emits and then emits all of the collected events and continues emitting what A gives. This is actually possible through

```
let bufferedSubject1 = Publishers.Concatenate(
   prefix: Publishers.PrefixUntilOutput(upstream: subject1, other: subject2).collect().flatMap(\.publisher),
   suffix: subject1)
```

`PrefixUntilOutput` will collect everything until B emits (`subject2`) and then switch to just regularly passing the output of it.

However if you run

```
let cancel = bufferedSubject1.combineLatest(subject2)    
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { c in
        print(c)
    }, receiveValue: { v in
        print(v)
    })
```

you are still missing the first value from A `(1,X)` -- this seems to be a bit like a race condition: Will `bufferedSubject1` have all values emitted first or does subject2 provide a value to `combineLatest` first?

What I think is interesting is that without any async calls, the behavior seems to be undefined. If you run the sample below, sometimes™️ you get all values emitted. Sometimes you are missing out on `(1,X)`. Since there is no async calls and no dispatchQueue switching here, I would even assume this is a bug.

You can "dirty fix" the race condition by providing a `delay` or even just a `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` between `bufferedSubject1` and `combineLatest`, so that before we continue the pipeline, we hand back control to the DispatchQueue and let subject2 emit to `combineLatest`.

However, I would not deem that elegant and **still looking for a solution** that uses `zip` semantics but without having to create an infinite collection of the same value (which does not play well with sequential processing and unlimited demand, the way I see it).

Sample:

```
var subject1 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
var subject2 = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let bufferedSubject1 = Publishers.Concatenate(prefix: Publishers.PrefixUntilOutput(upstream: subject1, other: subject2).collect().flatMap(\.publisher),
                                      suffix: subject1)

let bufferedSubject2 = Publishers.Concatenate(prefix: Publishers.PrefixUntilOutput(upstream: subject2, other: subject1).collect().flatMap(\.publisher),
                                      suffix: subject2)

let cancel = bufferedSubject1.combineLatest(subject2)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { c in
        print(c)
    }, receiveValue: { v in
        print(v)
    })

subject1.send(1)
subject1.send(2)
subject2.send("X")
subject2.send(completion: .finished)
subject1.send(3)
subject1.send(completion: .finished)
```

Comment: I too tried the `prefix(untilOutputFrom:)`, but also ran into a race condition. It seems to happen actually due to `Concatenate` - the suffix publisher is not subscribed to until the first one finishes, and that causes some race conditions. I'll write another approach below

Comment: I'm migrating my application from RxSwift, and am trying to solve this exact problem as well, and am sad to see how convoluted the solution has to be. In RxSwift, it "just worked". Kind of wish Apple would focus on making things that "just works"... Oh wait...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this was an interesting challenge and though it seemed deceptively simple, I couldn't find a simple elegant way.

Here's a working approach (though hardly elegant) that seems to not suffer from the race condition of using `PrefixUntilOutput`/`Concatenate` combo.

The idea is to use `combineLatest`, but one that emits as soon as the first publisher emits, with the other value being `nil` so that we don't lose the initial values. Here's a convenience operator that does that that I called `combineLatestOptional`:

```
extension Publisher {
    func combineLatestOptional<Other: Publisher>(_ other: Other) 
        -> AnyPublisher<(Output?, Other.Output?), Failure> 
        where Other.Failure == Failure {
        
        self.map { Optional.some($0) }.prepend(nil)
            .combineLatest(
                other.map { Optional.some($0) }.prepend(nil)
            )
            .dropFirst() // drop the first (nil, nil)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Armed with the above, the second step in the pipeline uses `Scan` to collect values into an accumulator until the other publisher emits the first value. There are 4 states of the accumulator that I'm representing this state with a `State<L, R>` type:

```
fileprivate enum State<L, R> {
    case initial         // before any one publisher emitted
    case left([L])       // left emitted; right hasn't emitted
    case right([R])      // right emitted; left hasn't emitted
    case final([L], [R]) // final steady-state
}
```

And the final operator `combineLatestLossless` is implemented like so:

```
extension Publisher {
   func combineLatestLossless<Other: Publisher>(_ other: Other) 
          -> AnyPublisher<(Output, Other.Output), Failure> 
          where Failure == Other.Failure {

      self.combineLatestOptional(other)
          .scan(State<Output, Other.Output>.initial, { state, tuple in
             switch (state, tuple.0, tuple.1) {
             case (.initial, let l?, nil):       // left emits first value
                return .left([l])                // -> collect left values

             case (.initial, nil, let r?):       // right emits first value
                return .right([r])               // -> collect right values

             case (.left(let ls), let l?, nil):  // left emits another
                return .left(ls + [l])           // -> append to left values

             case (.right(let rs), nil, let r?): // right emits another
                return .right(rs + [r])          // -> append to right values

             case (.left(let ls), _, let r?):    // right emits after left
                return .final(ls, [r])           // -> go to steady-state

             case (.right(let rs), let l?, _):   // left emits after right
                return .final([l], rs)           // -> go to steady-state

             case (.final, let l?, let r?):      // final steady-state
                return .final([l], [r])          // -> pass the values as-is
             default:
                fatalError("shouldn't happen")
             }
         })
         .flatMap { status -> AnyPublisher<(Output, Other.Output), Failure> in
            if case .final(let ls, let rs) = status {
               return ls.flatMap { l in rs.map { r in (l, r) }}
                   .publisher
                   .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
                   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
               return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
         }
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
}
```

The final `flatMap` creates a `Publishers.Sequence` publisher from all the accumulated values. In the final steady-state, each array would just have a single value.

The usage is simple:

```
let c = pub1.combineLatestLossless(pub2)
            .sink { print($0) }
```

Comment: From what I see, this is at least a working solution that is elegant in such a way that it does not require to write a completely new Publisher but works with the existing base elements.

I do agree that it is not elegant as in easy to understand. I am wondering if the trick with prepending nil (smart!) might help get rid of that State somehow.

I will leave the question open for some time, but if no one comes up with a better solution, I'll accept this. Many thanks!

Comment: There is a small typo in `combineLatestOptional` where you are accessing `second` but want to access `other`.

Comment: Also it seems there is something not quite right with `return Empty()` as in the production code I want to use this have seen premature completion of the stream. I assumed `Empty(completeImmediately: false)` might have been a required change but now the stream does not propagate completion at all. Any thoughts with regard to completion?

Comment: @Nicolas, fixed the "second" typo, thanks. `Empty` returned from a `flatMap` shouldn't terminate the pipeline... so, something else might be going on. Are you sure that you're properly retaining the returned `AnyCancellable` from the subscription?

Comment: You are right. The Empty() is not the problem here. I already fixed one problem with that. I am still having a problem that not all values being propagated but that is most likely something else. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh wow, I managed to get to the fatalError case. It seems that somehow it is possible to be in the initial state but r and l both having data. I don't understand how that would be possible. Did they say Combine makes async code easier? /s

Comment: This seems to be going too far. Follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593463/thread-safety-of-combinelatest-in-swift-combine

Comment: Interesting... I didn't think too much about the fatal error case, but if it did happen to jump from initial straight to steady, then just handle it the same way as a steady-state, i.e. `.final([l], [r])`

Answer (score 1):

> zip on the other hand will not work for me, because B only emits a single value.

Correct, so fix it so that that’s not true. Start a pipeline at B. Using flatmap turn its signal into a publisher for a sequence of that signal, repeated. Zip that with A.

Example:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let s1 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    let s2 = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let p1 = s1
        let p2 = s2.flatMap { (val:String) -> AnyPublisher<String,Never> in
            let seq = Array(repeating: val, count: 100)
            return seq.publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        p1.zip(p2)
            .sink{print($0)}
            .store(in: &storage)
        
        delay(1) {
            self.s1.send(1)
        }
        delay(2) {
            self.s1.send(2)
        }
        delay(3) {
            self.s1.send(3)
        }
        delay(2.5) {
            self.s2.send("X")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
(1, "X")
(2, "X")
(3, "X")
```

Comment: That's an interesting trick. I wonder what would be a generalized approach to actually create a `combineLatest` behavior that doesn't drop initial values, i.e. when either publisher could be the first to emit, could emit undefined number of values, etc...

Comment: @NewDev Yes, I feel like there's a hole here somewhere. Maybe there's an approach where we can use existing operators and `combineLatest` but I haven't found it. You have to test with lots of different values for the last `delay`, i.e. it mustn't matter precisely when the second publisher publishes.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found it either. Feels simple to do at first, until you start

Comment: This could be quite close. But I am not sure if that array created in the flatmap will work with lazy the way you suggest. If you replace the count with .max I even get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. In other words, if flatmap would allocate an array of `count` times the value, that would not be elegant in my view.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do it with a true lazy sequence but failed. I might have another way....

Comment: @matt "Using flatmap turn its signal into a publisher for a lazy infinite (or just very long)" makes me think about [Cycle](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Cycle.md) which also conforms to `LazySequenceProtocol` did you try that. Or do you think it might be of help here ?

Comment: maybe you tried that but FYI I just tried using `let seq = [val].cycled()` but `delay(3) { self.s1.send(3) }` never gets called. With `let seq = [val].cycled(times: 100000)` it does. and it may be lazier

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically speaking, you need to:

1. wait until `B` emits an event, collect all elements that `A` emits
2. store the element you just received from `B`
3. emit the pair of elements emitted so far by `A`
4. emit the rest of elements that `A` emits after `B` emitted it's element

An implementation of the above algoritm can be done like this:

```swift
// `share` makes sure that we don't cause unwanted side effects,
// like restarting the work `A` does, as we subscribe multiple
// times to this publisher
let sharedA = a.share()

// state, state, state :)
var latestB: String!

var cancel = sharedA
    // take all elements until `B` emits
    .prefix(untilOutputFrom: b.handleEvents(receiveOutput: { latestB = $0})) 
    // wait on those elements
    .collect()
    // uncollect them
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    // make sure we deliver the rest of elements from `A`
    .append(sharedA)
    // now, pair the outputs together
    .map { ($0, latestB) }
    .sink(receiveValue: {  print("\($0)") })
```

Maybe there's a way to avoid the state (`latestB`), and use a pure pipeline, couldn't yet find it, though.

---

P.S. As an added bonus, if `B` is expected to emit more than one element, than with a simple change we can support this scenario too:

```swift
let sharedA = a.share()
let sharedB = b.handleEvents(receiveOutput: { latestB = $0}).share()
var latestB: String!

var cancel = sharedA.prefix(untilOutputFrom: sharedB)
    .collect()
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .append(sharedA)
    .map { ($0, latestB)}
    .sink(receiveValue: {  print("\($0)") })
```